# angular-ui-select control themeing and customizing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I use Angular UI https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select.

I have a slight issue with my usage of the control. I would like to avoid altogether having a arrow (which seems to allow users to submit the whole form unfortunately). See red circle below:

[image: screen capture]

Here is the corresponding html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="address" class="control-label col-lg-3">signup.form.address</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ui-select ng-required="true" id="address" name="address" ng-model="signupForm.addressReference"  reset-search-input="false" theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select address...">{{$select.selected.description}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="address.reference as address in addresses track by $index" refresh="chooseAddress($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
                    {{address.description }}
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="signupNgFormCtrl.address.$error" ng-if="signupNgFormCtrl.$submitted" class="col-lg-3">
            <div ng-message="required">required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone please help?

Regards,

Comment: can you please create a plunker for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All templates are defined at the end of `select.js`. 
For instance, this one has `class="select2-arrow"`:

```
$templateCache.put("select2/match.tpl.html", 
    "<a ...> ... <span class=\"select2-arrow ui-select-toggle\" ng-click=\"$select.toggle($event)\"><b></b></span></a>");
```

or that one has `<span class=\"caret ui-select-toggle\" ng-click=\"$select.toggle($event)\"></span>`:

```
 $templateCache.put("bootstrap/match.tpl.html", ...
```

Both have `ng-click` event that might cause the effect you mention.
To avoid the arrow or the effect, you can override the template that corresponds to your theme.

Comment: Hi Dmitri. I am really required to override the template? Is there not an attribute I can use that would achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: What I find particulary annoying is the fact that clicking the arrow submits the form...

Comment: I don't know the plugin that well, you might try to open an issue there. But overriding is much faster solution. An "elegant" way could be to create you own custom directive that uses that one internally.

Comment: OK for overriding the templates! +50

Comment: Thanks! I like to "override" as it forces me to know how things work that I use, that way I can customize any 3rd party component to my needs, write my own tests to guarantee it works, and I don't depend on how active is the project. I might even override Angular, if they upset me too much :)

Comment: Of course, the clean way to override is to add your special modifier to the name of the component, so anyone can recognise the modification. Don't just patch and let it sit hidden in your code!